# Advantages of using monerod over Tor

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc, tor

According to the [README](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#using-tor), it seems like only the transactions sent from local RPC to the daemon get propagated through Tor. I am unable to understand why this choice was made/what its advantages may be. One advantage I can think of is that it would prevent a MITM in the circuit established between the sender and the receiver.

Also does the daemon relay the transaction only to other Tor nodes or do they relay information to all nodes in the Monero network?

Comment: What if i'd want to download/sync the blockchain via tor, is there a way to set it up? The reason being i am not willing to let my ISP see me have anything to do with xmr. Thanks and hope to get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymity networks make sense for remote nodes, not local. The monerod runs in the data center and wallets @home or mobile phone. [Here](https://monero.fail/) & [here](https://xmrguide42y34onq.onion.ly/remote_nodes) you can find some public .onion nodes.

Your linked README is out of date and contains the link to [ANONYMITY_NETWORKS.](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/docs/ANONYMITY_NETWORKS.md) Hint: monerod includes now addresses of I2P and Tor seed nodes. See: [add support for i2p and tor seed nodes](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/263579b217e82295939fa68b5b8f0af6dbf27562)
therefore `--add-peer` or `--add-exclusive-node` is no longer absolutely necessary.

monerod RPC & P2P port can be set up as a hidden service and you can connect your Monero (GUI|CLI|RPC) wallet over Tor to it.
The monerod P2P and blockchain synchronization will continue to be done via Clearnet as well. If any anonymity network is enabled, (inbound connections `--anonymous-inbound` and outbound connections `--tx-proxy`) transactions being broadcast that lack a valid "context" (i.e. the transaction did not come from a p2p connection), will only be sent to peers on anonymity networks.

Simplified:
**P2P** blockchain download & sync only over IPv4 because of sybil resistance and security.
**RPC & transactions** can be done via IP, IPv6, Tor and I2P. [Excellent monerod-reference](https://monerodocs.org/interacting/monerod-reference/)